# SQL Union with results in Order of Union

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I'm looking to write a Union between 2 tables where the 1st Union set of results appears before the second. (MSSQL 2014)

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17c9e/74

I've noticed this question asked a few times but for whatever reason the accepted answers aren't working for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076052/union-query-display-results-in-order-queries-are-written

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885261/order-result-sets-in-a-union

The 1st set of results returns:

```
userID   FirstName   LastName
-----------------------------
4        John        Snow
5        Joffrey     Baratheon
1        Tyrion      Lanister
```

And the 2nd results return:

```
userID   FirstName   LastName
-----------------------------
5        Joffrey     Baratheon
3        Daenerys    Targaryen
1        Tyrion      Lanister
```

Union gets rid of the duplicates which leaves userID 3 which should be appearing very last in my results. Final result:

```
userID   FirstName   LastName
-----------------------------
4        John        Snow
5        Joffrey     Baratheon
1        Tyrion      Lanister
3        Daenerys    Targaryen
```

The result I'm getting on SqlFiddle has userID -3 appearing second.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you included a table of what you expect to see as a result, just to be sure. Also, your result tables above don't match the query in your sqlfiddle sample.

Comment: The final result will look as it appears on the in sqlfiddle the only difference is userID 3 - Daenerys should be very last. The two results shown are whats returned by the individual queries before the union.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Username field, specifically. It's missing from these results, so it's unclear why the results should be ordered in that manner. Including it here helps ensure that the question itself is complete, even without the code sample at sqlfiddle.

Comment: choose any one of (MySQL & SQL Server) which is different DB Products.

Comment: Your question appears to be based on the (false) premise that each of the individual SELECTs is supposed to always return the results in the same order, even though there's no obvious sorting criterion in your examples, nor does your demo suggest any. If you want to have a solution to the problem as presented, you first need to address that issue, i.e. you need to provide a sorting criterion that can be used to guarantee the `4, 5, 1` order for the first set and `5, 3, 1` for the second. It's pointless to try to meet your requirements without that, so I'm voting to put this on hold as unclear.

Comment: And why exactly the other answers aren't working for you, if I may ask?

Comment: @mustaccio the answers in the links by the OP do not address the duplicating issue. If you add an order or sequence column to each internal set, the union operator will no longer eliminate duplicates (because the order is different in each set). However, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552019/sql-union-all-with-distinct) does have a working answer that addresses the duplication issue. It also turns out to be the same as what I posted below. So this question could be considered a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your sqlfiddle link, here's a brute force way to get what you're looking for. I inject an ordering value for each result set being unioned, group on matching values to get the minimum order, and then order by the minimum order for each grouped value.

```
SELECT userID, FirstName, LastName, UserName
FROM (
  SELECT userID, FirstName, LastName, UserName, MIN(UnionSet) UnionSetOrder
  FROM (
    SELECT u.userID, u.FirstName, u.LastName, u.Username, 1 as UnionSet
    FROM follows f INNER JOIN Users u ON f.Following = u.UserID
    WHERE follower=2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT u.UserId, u.FirstName, u.LastName, U.Username, 2 as UnionSet
    FROM users u 
    WHERE u.username LIKE '%a%' AND u.UserID <> 2
  ) x
GROUP BY userID, FirstName, LastName, UserName  
) y
ORDER BY UnionSetOrder, UserName
```

Note that this doesn't exactly match the results you're showing in your question, as they differ from what's in the code sample.

Comment: Perfecto brotha

Comment: Beautiful. The only solution I've ever found that actually works.

Answer (score 3):

To put it bluntly:  If you want a particular ordering of the rows, you must ask for it.

A pattern for `UNION` is

```
( SELECT ... )
UNION    -- tack on ALL or DISTINCT according to your need
( SELECT ... )
ORDER BY ...
```

There is no need for `ORDER BY` in the inner queries unless you want to use `LIMIT` and/or `OFFSET`.

If you need to force the "first" `SELECT` to come first (and don't have a column that happens to provide such ordering), then you may need an extra column:

```
( SELECT 1 AS seq, ... )
UNION    -- tack on ALL or DISTINCT according to your need
( SELECT 2 AS seq, ... )
ORDER BY seq, ...
```

If you really don't want `seq` cluttering` the output, then:

```
SELECT ...    -- without `seq`
    FROM (
        ( SELECT 1 AS seq, ... )
        UNION    -- tack on ALL or DISTINCT according to your need
        ( SELECT 2 AS seq, ... )
         ) AS u
    ORDER BY seq, ...
```

If you have some messy `JOINs`, it *may* be better to move some of them to the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: Can you attempt this in the SqlFiddle?
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/17c9e/74 if the link doesn't work try a refresh of the page.

Comment: By adding the seq field, won't the union operator consider matching records from the first and second sets as different?

Comment: (my opinion) The implementation of `UNION` is simple-minded.  In fact (until very recently), it blindly created a tmp table, regardless of what the statement was doing.)

Comment: This will result in duplicates if you're union'ing from the same table, right? I ended up doing: `select distinct on (id) * from 
(
  select *, 1 as result_set from table where ...
  union on (table.id) 
  select *, 2 as result_set from table
)
order by result_set, my_order_by_field
offset :offset limit :limit`

Comment: Is this valid syntax?  `distinct on (id) *`?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, its showing below result:

```
mysql> select * from set1 UNION select * from set2;
+---------+--------------+--------------+
| userID  | FirstName    | Lastname     |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
|       4 | John         | Snow         |
|       5 | Joffrey      | Baratheon    |
|       1 | Tyrion       | Lanister     |
|       3 | Daenerys     | Targaryen    |
+---------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Question is whether it's guaranteed to always work like that, though.

Comment: That isn't guaranteed: with no explicit ordering stated the query planner and engine are at liberty to pull things out in *any* order and may do something different as the data changes/grows or in later versions of the engine. I'm surprised you see this order: `UNION` without `ALL` implies `DISTINCT` which in turn is usually implemented by a sort by a primary-or-otherwise-unique key if one exists (I'm assuming userID is the PK here).

Comment: Were you unable to try this from SqlFiddle? If it doesn't immediately show try a refresh of the page.